# fixing div to top of page when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, blogger

I realise this question has being asked before - but I have trawled through almost everything I can find I want something like this - [Incredible Things](http://www.incrediblethings.com/web/cupcake-ipsum-filler-text-that-i-want-to-eat/)

here is what I have http://shoelesstestblog.blogspot.com

here is the code

```
          <div id="myElement">
          <div id="nav">
          <a href="">Home</a>
          </div>
          </div>

          <style>
          #myElement {
          background-color: #fff;
          color: #fff;
          font-family: 'Bitter';
          font-size: 13px;
          letter-spacing: 1px;
          line-height: 40px;
          margin-left: -180px;
          opacity: 0.9;
          text-align: center;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          width: 1280px;
          word-spacing: 20px;
          z-index: 5000;
          }
          </style>


          <script type="text/javascript"> 

          var yPosition; // save original y position of element here



          window.onload = function(){ // once entire page is loaded this function is fired
              // save original y position of element before it is scrolled
              yPosition = document.getElementById("myElement").offsetTop;
          }

          window.onscroll = function(){ // scrolling fires this function      

              var myElement = document.getElementById("myElement"); // for cleaner code

                  // compare original y position of element to y position of page
                  if( yPosition <= window.pageYOffset ){ 

                  // snap element to the top by changing css values of element
                  myElement.style.position = "fixed";
                  myElement.style.top = "0px"; 

              }
                else {          

                  // re-position to original flow of content
                  myElement.style.top = ""; // set to default       
              }                  
          }      

          </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element you wish to fix to the top of the page is `<div id="myElement">` I would suggest you add the attribute `position:fixed;` to the element's corresponding CSS.

like so:

```
 #myElement {
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      position:fixed;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Bitter';
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      line-height: 40px;
      margin-left: -180px;
      opacity: 0.9;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      width: 1280px;
      word-spacing: 20px;
      z-index: 5000;
      }
      </style>
```

I have also added the attributes `left: 0px; top: 0px;` to determine the elements position on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
position:fixed;
```

can achieve what you want